# Scala - Swagger : Using a trait as a response type for @Apiresponse

Tags: scala, swagger, swagger-ui

```
@ApiResponses(Array(
    new ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", response = classOf[ResultBase]),
    new ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error"),
  ))
```

and this is my trait:

```
@ApiModel(value="Event", description="Base class for events")
sealed trait ResultBase {
  @(ApiModelProperty @field)(value = "Id")
  val id: String
}
```

This is what I get in swagger.json

```
"responses" : {
          "200" : {
            "description" : "OK",
            "schema" : {
              "$ref" : "#/definitions/ResultBase"
            }
          },
          "500" : {
            "description" : "Internal server error"
          }
}
```

However, in `Swagger-ui` both Schema and Schema Model are empty.

Any way around this?